# Windows C++ Hex Viewer GUI component

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, components, vcl

I'm looking for a Windows C++ (or a Embarcadero Delphi/C++ Builder VCL component) GUI component for a professional looking Hex Viewer/Editor. While pretty easy to build up a rudimentary one I require a polished modern looking component. (Can handle arbitrary amounts of data, loading from some sort of stream as needed. Colors/Fonts customizable. Highlight byte selections/individual bytes)

2 of the more usable hex viewer/editor components from applications I've seen in action are below:

- http://niiconsulting.com/checkmate/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/fileinsight-2.jpg
- http://www.the-interweb.com/bdump/hexer/hexer-linux.png

Can anybody recommend anything?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Ajay: how is posting a website of a closed-source hex-editor going to help? besides, it's just a cheap modification of HxD: http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/

Comment: It wasn't clear if you were looking for open-source, free ware, professional or world class hex editor.

Comment: "Can handle arbitrary amounts of data" - a better design would be for your app to load the data, and the UI control to simply show a view of it (e.g., a window into the data - start and size.)  The control itself should probably not load and manipulate data, but a non-UI part of your app would, with the UI providing a view of it. That would also let you handle different data sizes, streams etc however you wanted with a unified interface to the UI.

Comment: I edited to add the C++Builder tag, since that's what you're using? "C++ or C++Builder" is pretty vague - the only reasonable assumption based on that and the Delphi tag is that you're using C++Builder.

Comment: @DavidM is profoundly interested in your tech stack intentions.  *(So interested that he'd like to fight over it, downvote, and remark.)*  Might you clarify what your requirements were back in 2011 so we can decide if he in 2015 has a single, rational, reasoned, and educated down vote?

Comment: The OP never clarified their intentions circa 2015 (4 years after posting) and still hasn't.  And not only that, the delphi tag wasn't added by the OP...it was someone else months later who [saw Delphi *mentioned* in the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6880289/revisions). I've reverted to the OP's original tags--for which my answer was on topic at time of writing--they say "Windows C++ or..." and those trying to say only Delphi answers are applicable seem to have an agenda.

Answer (score 1):

After a quick search on the interwebs, I found the following component for Delphi:

http://www.tkweb.eu/en/delphicomp/khexeditor.html

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention Qt as an option as a C++ library to use.  But it sounds like your circumstance may be flexible.  So if you're able to use it there are a couple of options I noticed.

There's a hex component that you can drop in as a replacement for `QPlainTextEdit` or whatever:

https://github.com/Simsys/qhexedit2

The webpage for that says that the size of data has in general to be below 10 megabytes.  A heavier-weight paging solution exists as a program called LFhex (source in the download)

http://stoopidsimple.com/lfhex

Comment: The OP is using C++Builder, which uses the VCL not Qt.

Comment: @DavidM OP says, and I quote: *"I'm looking for a **Windows C++** (**or** a Embarcadero Delphi/C++ Builder VCL component)"*.  The question is also tagged [tag:c++]. Qt is a C++ library, and you can link it into Windows C++ programs.

Comment: Yeah, but you need to read between the lines. If they want a Windows C++ for the Embarcadero C++ platform... then... you see? The VCL (if you didn't know) wraps WinAPI controls and so a pure WinAPI control would be useable from the VCL or C++ Builder. Qt, however, is not pure Windows, and is not easy to mix and match with an entirely different UI framework.

Comment: @DavidM Yeah, but going around downvoting people for no real reason on questions from 2011 just because you're feeling ornery... especially if they have less than 20 rep points (I don't personally care, outside of the symbolic nature of "what's your deal")... requires a different kind of "reading between the lines".  But don't worry, I upvoted Simsys to compensate.

Comment: I'm not "feeling ornery", HostileFork, and I'm sorry you think so. I downvoted an answer that is inapplicable to or at absolute best pretty incompatible with the technology the OP is using, and left an answer explaining the down vote. I feel this is absolutely acceptable and correct SO behaviour. As for two years ago, this question popped up on the recently modified list, which is why I saw it. (There was a new answer.) I don't feel age somehow exempts answers from either up or down voting... why would it?

Comment: @DavidM w/between-line-reading and viewing your profile, I can see that you work *for* Delphi *(hence your interest in the tag)*.  I really don't know what a "c++ builder" is and that sounds like Delphi is trading on C++'s name, but anyway...you shouldn't read a statement like *"I'm looking for a Windows C++ (or a Embarcadero Delphi/C++ Builder VCL component)"* to mean *"I'm looking for an Embarcadero Delphi/C++ Builder VCL component (or something compatible)"*. With corporate SO involvement, don't let "curation" cloud the important work here of welcoming new users to an information ecosystem.

Comment: I do not work for Delphi, no.  It's one of several languages I use.  And, as I noted, it's not that the OP wanted a VCL component specifically - they needed either a VCL one or a *Windows* one.  And, Qt does not produce native WinAPI controls, and integrating Qt controls into their development environment with a different UI system would be well-nigh impossible. If you "don't know what a c++ builder [sic] is" then, well, that explains your confusion. There's an [entire C++ ecosystem out there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2BBuilder#Version_history) you don't know about :)

Comment: Please don't accuse me of corporate shilling - I feel that crosses a certain line :( I understand from your comments that you aren't aware of the Delphi and C++ Builder ecosystems, and that's ok - it just means you don't know about them. FWIW, Borland had one of the earliest C++ compilers in the early nineties (maybe even eighties?) and for many years was regarded as much better than Microsoft. That compiler still exists today in the form of C++ Builder. It shares a common RTL and UI system with Delphi, and can link code written in both languages into the one app. Rather neat. So there you go.

Comment: @DavidM [Well aware of Borland, thanks](http://blog.hostilefork.com/inquiry-teenage-turbo-c-coding/), but do consider the balance in your comments and voting.  There's extra responsibility to not see every question with Delphi lenses when it asks about Windows C++ "or...", not less...

Comment: *sigh* I viewed through *C++ & Windows lenses*, and *lenses knowing about the technology stack the OP was using.* I have made that abundantly clear. Please stop accusing me of working for a company I don't work for, of corporate shilling, of voting based on another language. Your answer was in my view not useful / applicable for the OP, possibly because you may not to know about the OP's tech stack. That's fine, it happens, but it's why I gave a -1 and comment. Please, let us stop this constant back and forth arguing for your answer over a single, rational, reasoned, and educated down vote.

Comment: @DavidM The OP's last login was two days ago.  Perhaps he can clarify if he was only interested in Delphi answers or not.  And if you use a corporate site as your referral link, that indeed doesn't prove a business association, but it does suggest fanboyism at least.

Comment: HostileFork, seriously. Of course he/she is not interested in Delphi answers only. He/she is interested in *Windows C++ _or_ VCL controls*. VCL = C++ Builder. Windows C++ = WinAPI controls, or (given they specify the IDE they're using) controls written in C++ able to be used with C++Builder. While there are many things that fit that description, without an awful lot of work, a Qt control is probably not one of them. Thus my comment & downvote. I appreciate you posting an answer, but it is ok SO behaviour to downvote when you feel an answer does not answer the OP's needs.

Comment: And there's no need for the personal attacks. I did ask you stop that. Please keep the discussion civilised and on technical, on-topic-for-SO matters.

Answer (score 0):

QHexEdit2 is now able to edit large files (> 2 GBytes) and is available for Qt4, Qt5, PyQt4, PyQt5. It is now hosted on Github

https://github.com/Simsys/qhexedit2

Comment: The OP is using C++Builder, which uses the VCL not Qt.